# Typeface to DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker, typeface

I've tried to find something similar but couldn't find anything on SO... Just wondering if is any posibility to change the font on a datepicker in Android? And most important is how to do that?

Here is a part of my code:

```
public class FirstPage extends ActionBarActivity {
DatePicker datePicker;
Typeface tf;
EditText et;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_page);
    setVar();
    setFont();
}

private void setFont() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String fontPath = "fonts/StarshineMF.ttf";
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
}

private void setVar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
}
```

}

And the XML code:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for applying font on datepicker

```
 DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
 LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) datePicker.getChildAt(0);
 LinearLayout layout = layout1.getChildAt(0);

// day
LinearLayout day = (LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(0);
setFontOnPicker(day);

// month
LinearLayout month = (LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(1);
setFontOnPicker(month);

// year
LinearLayout year = (LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(2);
setFontOnPicker(year);
```

apply font by calling this method

```
private void setFontOnPicker(LinearLayout ll) {

    EditText et = (EditText) ll.getChildAt(1);
    et.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14);
    et.setTypeface(youtTypeface);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it did work for me ,this code allows you to override style for datepicker (font and/or the divider color) :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatePicker datePicker =  findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    applyStyLe(datePicker);
}


private void applyStyLe(DatePicker datePickerDialog) {
    Resources system = Resources.getSystem();
    int dayNumberPickerId = system.getIdentifier("day","id", "android");
    int monthNumberPickerId = system.getIdentifier("month", "id", "android");
    int yearNumberPickerId = system.getIdentifier("year", "id", "android");

    NumberPicker dayNumberPicker = datePickerDialog.findViewById(dayNumberPickerId);
    NumberPicker monthNumberPicker = datePickerDialog.findViewById(monthNumberPickerId);
    NumberPicker yearNumberPicker= datePickerDialog.findViewById(yearNumberPickerId);

    overrideStyle(dayNumberPicker);
    overrideStyle(monthNumberPicker);
    overrideStyle(yearNumberPicker);
}

private void overrideStyle(NumberPicker number_picker) {
    final int count = number_picker.getChildCount();
    Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font.otf"); //declare your font here

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        try {
            //this allows you to change the divider color
            Field dividerField = number_picker.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectionDivider");
            dividerField.setAccessible(true);
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));
            dividerField.set(number_picker, colorDrawable);

            //this allows you to change the font
            Field wheelpaint_field = number_picker.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
            wheelpaint_field.setAccessible(true);
            ((Paint) wheelpaint_field.get(number_picker)).setTypeface(tf);
            ((EditText) number_picker.getChildAt(i)).setTypeface(tf);

            number_picker.invalidate();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTxtClr", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTxtClr", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.w("setNumberPickerTxtClr", e);
        }
    }
  }
}
```